# Derrived Classes and Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Sorry about the vague title.

I was trying to fix a problem in a fairly large codebase. The fix requires me to have `ChildClass` and `ChildListElementClass` both supplied with the other as a template argument. I believe the problem I'm having is that `myType` in `ParentListElementClass` is not overwritten with `typedef  ChildClass<ChildListElementClass> myType;` in the derived class `ChildListElementClass`.
How can I make this work? Thank you very much!

Compiler says:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'void ParentListElementClass<ChildClass>::AddX(ParentClass<ParentListElementClass<ChildClass>> *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'ParentClass<ChildListElementClass> *const ' to 'ParentClass<ParentListElementClass<ChildClass>> *'
```

I wrote the following minimal testcase to demonstrate my problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class ElementType>
class ParentClass;

template <class ParentType>
class ParentListElementClass
{
public:
    ParentListElementClass(){};
    ~ParentListElementClass(){};
    typedef ParentClass<ParentListElementClass> myType;
    myType *x;
    void AddX(myType *m){
        m->speak();
    };
};
```

---

```
class ChildListElementClass;

template <class ElementType>
class ParentClass
{
public:
    ParentClass(){};
    ~ParentClass(){};   
    ElementType m;
    void DoSomething() {
        std::cout << "ParentList\n";
        m.AddX(this);
    }
    virtual void speak(){ std::cout << "Parent\n";}
};
```

---

```
class ChildClass;

class ChildListElementClass : public ParentListElementClass<ChildClass>
{
public:
    ChildListElementClass(){};
    ~ChildListElementClass(){};
};


class ChildClass : public ParentClass<ChildListElementClass>
{
public:
    ChildClass(){};
    ~ChildClass(){};
    void speak(){ std::cout << "Child\n"; }
};
```

---

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ChildClass Child;
    ChildListElementClass ChildListElement;
    Child.DoSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit: Working Version with help from itachi:**

```
template <typename ElementType, typename ListType> class ParentListClass;

template <typename ElementType, typename ListType>
class ParentElementClass
{
    typedef ParentListClass<ElementType, ListType> myType;
};

template <typename ElementType, typename ListType>
class ParentListClass{};

class ChildListClass;

class ChildElementClass : public ParentElementClass<ChildElementClass, ChildListClass>{};    

class ChildListClass : public ParentListClass<ChildElementClass, ChildListClass>{};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but no matter how I think of it, changing ParentListElementClass appears hard to avoid. You could try something on these lines..

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct MyTypedefCase
{
    typedef T<U> _type;
};
```

Then rewrite ParentListElementClass as

```
template <class ParentType, typename T, typename U>
class ParentListElementClass
{
     //typedef ParentClass<ParentListElementClass> myType;     Change this to below line
     typedef typename MyTypedefCase<T,U>::_type myType;
     //Rest of your code
};
```

and

```
class ChildListElementClass : public ParentListElementClass<ChildClass,ChildClass,ChildListElementClass>
```

I have never done something this complex with templates So I don't gurantee that it would work but if I had to go about it with minimal changes this would be the way. Perhaps someone could look into this solution and offer changes or imprvement.

Comment: Thank you very much. If this compiles I'll go with it. I'd be interested if there's a solution with less changes though since I'd like to mess as less as possible with the original codebase.

Comment: It did not quite work this way because the template argument `T` in `MyTypedefCase` requires it's own template list to make `typedef T<U> _type` work. 
However I changed your code a little so all classes would take themselfs as template arguments `template <typename ElementType, typename ListType>` and now it does work. Thank you again.